# Do tocotrienols reduce tocopherol uptake?

Tags: micronutrients, vitamin-e

I've read that a-tocopherol competitively reduces the uptake of tocotrienols.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3681510/

What I'd like to know is: Do tocotrienols competitively reduce the uptake of a-tocopherol?

Comment: Nutrition questions that aren't directly related to medical treatments are off topic here, so I removed your second and third questions. If you disagree with my edits you can revert them, but there's a good chance your question will be closed if you do.

Comment: And can you cite the source where you read this? We require questions to demonstrate a basic level of prior research.

Comment: @CareyGregory It seems odd to actively block someone from receiving information, haha. I fail to see the hard delineation between the highly upvoted question two threads down on "Should I drink coconut water daily?" and my question about the pharmacokinetics of vitamin e isomers.

Comment: Well, if we didn't block some types of questions this would be a free-for-all "diagnose me please!" forum. You have a good point and I'm not too thrilled with the coconut water question and many others related to nutrition. We get bombarded with them and you'll find lengthy discussions about that type of question in meta. It's not easy to pick out which ones should remain and which should be closed. If it were up to me, I would nuke virtually 100% of nutrition questions. But thanks for adding the link. You made it a good question.

Comment: @CareyGregory I might add, no where in that lengthy peer-reviewed scientific journal article does it mention whether or not tocotrienols would meet the medical necessity for vitamin e (tocopherol.) Is this not known? Are there better stack exchanges for nutrition questions?  I found this one, but it says not to talk about food / nutrition if it's not related to fitness: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition (It's odd because in a way, nutrition is at the core of health / medical science / fitness.)

Comment: Unfortunately, no, there is no exchange where nutrition questions in general are openly welcome, not even on the cooking exchange. You could always create a proposal in Area 51. It seems to me the demand is there.

Comment: You can make your question more appealing if you quote the part of the linked article that mentions the interaction between tochopherol and tocotrienols. If not, someone else would need to do dig throgh the article. Also, can you mention the context  and how can you benefit from the answer? Is it about the effects/side effects of tocotrienol supplements?

Comment: Maret Traber at Oregon State University is probably the lead scientist on Vitamin E in the United States, so you might want to follow her work. http://terra.oregonstate.edu/2006/07/to-conquer-vitamin-e/

Comment: Here is an interview of Traber regarding forms of Bitamin E, but she does far more work than just this. http://www.drpasswater.com/nutrition_library/traber2.html